# How to increase a double by 3%

Tags: c#, global, currency, percentage, calculation

I would like the price to change whenever the checkbox is checked and to revert back if it is unchecked.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (chkbBreakfast.Checked) // checks if breakfast is checked 
{
    sBreakFast = "Yes";
    CGlobals.sBreakFast = "YES";

    double dPercent;
    dPercent = 0.03;

    double dtotal = Convert.ToDouble(CGlobals.sPrice) * dPercent / 100;

    CGlobals.sPrice = Convert.ToString(dtotal);

    lblTotalCost.Text = CGlobals.sPrice;
}
else
    sBreakFast = "No";
```

Comment: Tip: Use a `bool` value instead of "YES"/"Yes". Use `Decimal` for currency values instead of `double` to avoid floating-point errors. Avoid the use of global variables.

Comment: @Dai thank you. and i am using global variables to populate labels across forms.

Comment: have you tried attaching an event handler on your checkbox?

Comment: Seems to be something wrong there. The thing you have called total is only 3% of the price. Surely you need to multiply it by 1.03 rather than 0.03.

Comment: Another tip: Avoid assigning the modified value to same variable, you wouldn't know whether 3% is added already or not. The `dtotal` you wrote is actually 0.03%, not 3% nor 103%.

Comment: @AdamG well, that he knows i guess. That's what you learn in maths in 6/7th grade

Comment: @Dai - Don't use `bool`. Use an `enum` - something like `public enum Breakfast { Yes, No }`.

Comment: @Zenith9833 - There are no global variables in C#. The language doesn't support them. What have is static fields/properties on a class.

Comment: @Zenith9833 - Why is `CGlobals.sPrice` a `string`? That's weird. Why not store as a `decimal` and avoid all of that conversion?

Comment: @Zenith9833 Even if it was `global` it changes nothing about the calculation behind increasing something by 3%.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues: you store your price in global variable, which is defined as `string` - it shouldn't be, you should declare it as `decimal` (as mentioned in comments).

Now, if you want to do all this increasing and decreasing by 3% based on value in checkbox, it's reasonable to put all this code in checkbox `CheckedChanged` event. I did so in below code.

And the reason why your code is not working is this: you declare your percentage as `0.03` and then you multiply by `dPercent / 100` which is wrong, because it is `0.03%`! That's why it isn't working.

Below I give you the code, that should get you started :)

```
private void chkbBreakfast_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkbBreakfast.Checked) // checks if breakfast is checked 
    {
        sBreakFast = "Yes";
        // for this code to work, you must delcare sPrice as decimal
        CGlobals.sPrice *= 1.03;
    }
    else
    {
        sBreakFast = "No";
        // to revert increasing by 3%
        CGlobals.sPrice /= 1.03;
    }
    //you have to check, if you want this global variable set here
    CGlobals.sBreakFast = sBreakFast;
    lblTotalCost.Text = CGlobals.sPrice.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend against changing the "raw" price - I'd have one variable for the "raw" price, and then a computed property that takes all the "extras" into account. Otherwise there's a risk of data loss when multiplying and then dividing by 1.03, even as a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You're making your life harder for yourself by putting your logic in your UI. You have a class where you're putting the values already so make that work for you and keep the UI clean.

To start with define an `enum` for your `Breakfast` value - avoid strings and avoid booleans for this. Your code will be much easier to read.

Then, your `CGlobals` class should be defined like this:

```
public static class CGlobals
{
    public static Breakfast Breakfast = Breakfast.No;
    public static decimal BreakfastPremium = 1.03m;
    public static decimal BasePrice = 10m;
    public static decimal FinalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return BasePrice * (Breakfast == Breakfast.Yes ? BreakfastPremium : 1m);
        }
    }
}
```

All of the details and business rules are stored there. Then your UI is dead simple:

```
CGlobals.Breakfast = chkbBreakfast.Checked ? Breakfast.Yes : Breakfast.No;
lblTotalCost.Text = CGlobals.FinalPrice.ToString();
```

That's it. No `if` statement. No calculations in your UI. Simple.

Ideally `CGlobals` shouldn't be a `static class` - but that's a whole other conversation to have. For now it should be fine, but don't stick with this pattern for the long-term as it will cause you a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your calculation. 
I assume dPercent value is in decimal, so 3% = 0.03

```
var dPercent = 0.03;
if (chkbBreakfast.Checked) // checks if breakfast is checked 
{
    sBreakFast = "Yes";

    var dtotal = Convert.ToDouble(CGlobals.sPrice) * (1 + dPercent);

    CGlobals.sPrice = Convert.ToString(dtotal);
}
else
{
    var dtotal = Convert.ToDouble(CGlobals.sPrice) / (1 + dPercent);

    CGlobals.sPrice = Convert.ToString(dtotal);
}

lblTotalCost.Text = CGlobals.sPrice;
```

Comment: You should use `decimal` rather than `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have two separate "storage" areas for the value: `CGlobals.sPrice` and `lblTotalCost.Text`. You're trying to show a changed (+3%) price to the user. You've correctly identified that when you overwrite the value everywhere, it's less than obvious to revert to the old value, since you'd be required to create the opposite calculation. Doing double work is never a good thing.

To that end, I suggest you change the following:

- Change `CGlobals.Price` to be a decimal.
- `CGlobals.Price` will always store the **base** price (without the 3%)
- The content of `lblTotalCost` will be set to the correct price (with or without the 3%)

*Redacted the unrelated code for readability:*

```
if (chkbBreakfast.Checked) // checks if breakfast is checked 
{
    lblTotalCost.Text = CGlobals.Price * 1.03;
}
else
{
    lblTotalCost.Text = CGlobals.Price;
}
```

Some things to mention:

- Note that you don't need to change the value of `CGlobals.Price` anymore, or at least not for this particular piece of logic.
- Note that you don't need to explicitly convert `CGlobals.Price` to a string in order to put it as the label's text. In C#, every object is inherently able to be cast to a string. For C# types (such as number types), you don't need to worry about converting to a string.
- I assume the `s` in `sPrice` is because it's a string. Prepending variable name with hints about their type isn't good practice, in my opinion. It hinders readability for no justifiable benefit.
- Others have already pointed out the error in your calculation. They are correct about that, but just to reiterate:

  - You're taking the percent of a percent. Either set `dPercent = 3`, or remove the `/ 100`.
  - Your formula is doing `price * 0.03`. For $100, that results in $3. That's not **adding** 3% to the price, it's calculating the 3% by itself. In order to add it to the existing price, you need to do `total = price + (price * 0.03)`. This is the mathematical equivalent of `price * 1.03`.
- You mention that you're using static variables in order to show the same information across the application. I would advise against that, but this is off-topic for your current question.

  - However, if you need the recalculated price to be available in all forms, and are not going to stop using the statics, then I suggest you do the following:
  - Make a second static variable called `CGlobals.PriceCalculated` (decimal).
  - In the above code, when you set the label's text, also set `CGlobals.PriceCalculated` to the same (number) value.
  - You could also make `CGlobals.PriceCalculated` a string, but it's better to keep it as a number and have the UI convert it to a string when it needs to. This means you don't have to reconvert from a string back to a number all the time.
  - `CGlobals.Price` will still only contain the base price, never the recalculated price.